# Python Selenium: How do I add a new line at the correct position?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cannot figure out how to add a new line at the proper spot.

The link.txt file contains 2 links that I'm looping thru. The output creates a new text file called names.txt

The first link contains: "Violet Myers" and "JMac". The second link contains: "Charly Summer" and "Kyle Mason".

**The important thing is, the new line has to come AFTER I'm done with each link. So for instance if there are 3 names within the same link, those 3 names should be on the same line.**

The output I'm getting right now in names.txt:

```
Violet Myers,
JMac,
Charly Summer,
Kyle Mason,
```

The desired output in names.txt:

```
Violet Myers, JMac
Charly Summer, Kyle Mason
```

The code I have right now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pickle as pkl
import shutil, json, os, re
from sys import platform
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import \
    NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException, \
    StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


one = open("link.txt", "r")

for two in one.readlines():
  driver.get(two)
  for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sc-1b6bgon-7'):
      with open("names.txt", "a") as testtxt:
        testtxt.write(element.text + "," + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1=[element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sc-1b6bgon-7')]
with open("names.txt", "a") as testtxt:
    testtxt.write(', '.join(arr1)+"\n")
```

Try joining the array with a , and writing it to the text file.